# Unable to parse some simple JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here, but I've been at it for a while.

Here's an example of the JSON I get back:

```
[
    {
        "0": "Horses",
        "1": "Cows",
        "Category": "Animals",
        "total_number": "90"
    }
]
```

I get this back via AJAX...my `success` function looks like this:

```
success: function(data) {
          console.log(data); //this gives me the above JSON
        var tot_num = data.total_number; //this comes back as undefined
 }
```

Why is that last variable (`tot_num`) coming back as undefined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It retunrns undefined because it is an array that is being returned with an object in the first index.

```
data[0].total_number
```

Comment: That was it. Finally figured it out about 5 seconds before your response.

Answer (score 3):

Because `data` is actually an **array that contains your object** at index 0 -- you can see this by the extra brackets `[ ... ]`.

Try this instead:

```
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var tot_num = data[0].total_number;
}
```